# Set-cookie header not set for capacitor 4 android

Tags: express, cookies, capacitor

I'm sending a cookie in response from express server as follows.

```
res.cookie('jwt', token, { httpOnly: true, maxAge: MAX2DAYS });
```

Now I've migrated from capacitor 3 to capacitor 4 for ours android app. Where the cookies are not recieved in the response headers. Do capacitor 4 has a different way to recieve and set cookies.

Note: For our Web app, the cookies are recieved and set as expected.

Answer (score 1):

Capacitor 3 supported cookies through the [@capacitor-community/http plugin](https://github.com/capacitor-community/http).

Capacitor 4 (from 4.3) supports cookies through the included [HTTP](https://capacitorjs.com/docs/apis/http) and [Cookies](https://capacitorjs.com/docs/apis/cookies) plugins.

This is a complete rewrite of the way HTTP requests are handled; [historical context can be found here](https://github.com/ionic-team/capacitor/issues/5145).